# Spring Boot - Build maven project (JAR-file) inside docker container

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, jenkins

I have a spring boot project running a VueJS app with the following folder structure:

```
root
+-- client
|   +-- [vue app]
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- server
|   +-- [spring boot app]
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- pom.xml
```

From the `client` I am running the following commands through the `pom.xml` when building the app. The script is installing `npm` and running `npm run build` to create the `dist/` folder to be copied in the next code snippet.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Install our node and npm version to run npm/node scripts-->
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v11.5.0</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Install all project dependencies -->
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Build and minify static files -->
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the `pom.xml`-file in the `server` directory I have the following config to copy the resources from the `client/dist/` to the static assets of the `server` classpath:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <!-- Copy Vue files to src-folder in server -->
        <id>copy Vue.js frontend content</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/public</outputDirectory>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/client/dist</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <!-- Make sure assets are added to static/ folder in vue.config.js-->
                        <include>static/</include>
                        <include>index.html</include>
                        <include>favicon/</include>>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The final goal is to have the app get built by a jenkins pipeline into a docker container.

However, my problem is that due to production settings I cannot download or install node / npm through maven (all external packages are blocked due to security reasons).

Therefore I need a way to build the vue app, and copy the files to the classpath when creating the `.jar` file without actually doing this through maven.

An idea was to use a docker image with `node` installed and do the building through the docker image. However, I am clueless of the actual approach of this. If someone has an idea that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get your Maven/Java artifacts from? Do you have a company Nexus/Artifactory?

Comment: Yes, we do have an artifactory specific to the company in question

Comment: Couldn't you get the npm packages through the Artifactory?

Comment: I am working as a consultant so I don't have access to that. But I believe the access problem is just from maven, so perhaps it's possible to create a `docker-compose.yml` with `node` as a preqrequisite for the app would work? And then do the building part inside the docker container?